# Open CMD from a PowerShell script, and run multiple commands within it

Tags: powershell, cmd

I'm working on a maintenance script and would like to call some cmd commands from powershell. Right now I would have called a second script but I would like to create a single one for better ease of maintenance. I tried this approach:

```
$commands = @'
@echo off
set TC_PWF_FILE=ABC
set TC_ROOT=ABC
set TC_DATA=ABC
call %TC_DATA%\tc_profilevars
preferences_manager -h
pause
'@

$commands | cmd
```

When running this in a `cmd.exe` (Command Prompt) session, the "preferences manager" give the correct output unlike when running inside a powershell script. I tried to open a `cmd.exe` session and invoke the commands but struggled.

I'll get an error like this:

```
cmd : At C:\plm\Tc13_Tasks\Maintenance\Test.ps1:15 char:13
+ $commands | cmd
+ ~~~ + CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:String) [], RemoteException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

So my guess is that the `preferences_manager` command is not recognized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your symptom implies that you're using the *ISE*, so the standard advice applies:

- **The Windows PowerShell *ISE* is [no longer actively developed](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/components/ise/introducing-the-windows-powershell-ise#support) and [there are general reasons not to use it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57134096/45375) (bottom section), notably not being able to run the modern, cross-platform [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) edition.**
- The actively developed, cross-platform editor that offers the best PowerShell development experience is [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) with its [PowerShell extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.PowerShell).

---

**Your code works *as-is* if you simply run your PowerShell script in either a regular console window, in Windows Terminal, or in the integrated terminal of Visual Studio Code.**

That said, note that the `pause` call won't be effective (execution won't pause; it'll act as if you had already pressed a key); you can work around that with `pause <CON`, but do *not* do that in the ISE - your script will hang, because the ISE fundamentally doesn't support *interactive* console applications.

Also, *if* your command string contained *non*-ASCII-range characters (it doesn't), you would need to execute `$OutputEncoding = [Console]::InputEncoding` also in the environments listed above, because `$OutputEncoding` defaults to ASCII(!) in *Windows PowerShell* (except in the ISE, see below), and - surprisingly - (BOM-less) UTF-8 in *PowerShell (Core) 7+*.<sup>[1]</sup>

---

**In the ISE**, you need a **workaround**:

The **problem** is that not only does the [**`$OutputEncoding`** preference variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Preference_Variables#outputencoding) unexpectedly default to **UTF-8** - whereas `[Console]::InputEncoding` defaults to the system's active legacy OEM code page, and `[Console]::OutputEncoding` defaults to the legacy ANSI code page(!), the specific encoder used behind the scenes ***prepends a BOM* to the data being piped to an external program**, even though use of a BOM is normally only expected at the start of a *file*.

`cmd.exe` doesn't recognize the BOM, and therefore *misinterprets the first line*.

The **solution** is to set `$OutputEncoding` to `[Console]::InputEncoding` to ensure that the string piped to `cmd.exe` use the character encoding that `cmd.exe` expects:

```bash
# Set the encoding that PowerShell should use to send
# strings to external programs to the one that cmd.exe expects.
$OutputEncoding = [Console]::InputEncoding

# Now your code should work.
# (I've removed the `pause` call, for the reasons explained above.)
$commands = @'
@echo off
set TC_PWF_FILE=ABC
set TC_ROOT=ABC
set TC_DATA=ABC
call %TC_DATA%\tc_profilevars
preferences_manager -h
'@

$commands | cmd
```

---

<sup>[1] While PowerShell 7+ *itself* commendably defaults to (BOM-less), *external programs* still use the legacy OEM code page by default, and PowerShell uses that code page to decode output *received from* external programs. As such, it would make sense to use the same code page on *sending data to* external programs, yet `$OutputEncoding` defaults to UTF-8. See [GitHub issue #7233](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7233) for a discussion.</sup>

Comment: You're right, been using the ISE for dev stuff. Running the PS script in a regular console is working just fine. Will keep this in mind for upcoming stuff I have to do. 

Thank you!

Comment: Glad to hear it, @Moritz; my pleasure.